Is there a way to remove space in App Bar NestedScrollConnection?
I am trying to collapsing the App Bar with my Custom NestedScrollConnection but it make space in App Bar place when I Scroll. The App Bar goes up when I scroll but the space of App Bar in the Background of App Bar doesn't go up?
My Custom NestedScrollConnection Class:
class CollapsingAppBarNestedScrollConnection(
    val appBarMaxHeight: Int,
) : NestedScrollConnection {

    var appBarOffset by mutableIntStateOf(0)
        private set

    override fun onPreScroll(
        available: Offset,
        source: NestedScrollSource,
    ): Offset {
        val delta = available.y.roundToInt()
        val newsOffset = appBarOffset + delta
        val previousOffset = appBarOffset
        appBarOffset = newsOffset.coerceIn(
            -appBarMaxHeight,
            0
        )
        val consumed = appBarOffset - previousOffset

        return Offset(0f, consumed.toFloat())
    }
}


MY UI:
val density = LocalDensity.current

val appBarMaxHeight = with(density) { (70).dp.roundToPx() }

val connection = remember(appBarMaxHeight) {
    CollapsingAppBarNestedScrollConnection(appBarMaxHeightPx)
}

Scaffold(
   topBar = {
      TopAppBar(
         title = {
            Text("Top App Bar")
         },
         modifier = Modifier
             .offset { IntOffset(0, connection.appBarOffset) }
      )
   },
   modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()
       .nestedScroll(connection)
) {
   // Content
}


Video gif, before
Video gif, After

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

When you use the offset Modifier, the space where the Composable originally was remains reserved. This is because

it avoids recomposition when the offset is changing, and also adds a graphics layer that prevents unnecessary redrawing of the context when the offset is changing.

Thus, the offset is applied on another layer and does not actually impact the Composable hierarchy. This means that you can't use the space where the TopAppBar originally was for other Composables.
To achieve this, you would usually use a default NestedScrollConnection like TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior.
If you actually need a custom NestedScrollConnection the TopAppBar to shift out of the screen at scrolling, implement this using the height Modifier together with wrapContent:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyCollapsibleTopAppBarDemo() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val myNestedScrollConnection = remember {
        MyNestedScrollConnection(TopAppBarDefaults.TopAppBarExpandedHeight.dpToPx(density))
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(myNestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(myNestedScrollConnection.currentHeaderHeightPx.toInt().pxToDp(density))
                    .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.Bottom, true),
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.LightGray
                ),
                title = {
                    Text("Demonstration")
                }
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            items(50) { item ->
                Text("Item $item", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Dp.dpToPx(density: Density) = with(density) { this@dpToPx.toPx() }
fun Int.pxToDp(density: Density) = with(density) { this@pxToDp.toDp() }

Update your custom NestedScrollConnection like this:
class MyNestedScrollConnection(
    val appBarMaxHeight: Float,
) : NestedScrollConnection {

    var currentHeaderHeightPx by mutableFloatStateOf(appBarMaxHeight)
        private set

    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
        val delta = available.y
        // add this if statement when you only want the TopAppBar to appear when scrolled fully to the top
        if (delta >= 0) {
            return Offset.Zero
        }
        // 
        val newHeaderHeightPx = currentHeaderHeightPx + delta
        val previousHeaderHeightPx = currentHeaderHeightPx
        currentHeaderHeightPx = newHeaderHeightPx.coerceIn(0f, appBarMaxHeight)
        val consumed = currentHeaderHeightPx - previousHeaderHeightPx
        return Offset(x = 0f, y = consumed)
    }

    // additionally add this fun when you only want the TopAppBar to appear when scrolled fully to the top
    // this code is very similar to onPreScroll, so you could extract a common method for it
    override fun onPostScroll(
        consumed: Offset,
        available: Offset,
        source: NestedScrollSource
    ): Offset {
        val delta = available.y
        val newHeaderHeightPx = currentHeaderHeightPx + delta
        val previousHeaderHeightPx = currentHeaderHeightPx
        currentHeaderHeightPx = newHeaderHeightPx.coerceIn(0f, appBarMaxHeight)
        val consumedLocally = currentHeaderHeightPx - previousHeaderHeightPx
        return Offset(x = 0f, y = consumedLocally)
    }
}

Output:

Note:
This does not animate the CenterAlignedTopAppBar color when the content is scrolled.

Actually I were found the Problem I add Height modifier in My TopAppBar Like this:-

Almost similar to your Answer

In One Screen I want behaviour like This in Top Bar, How Can I achieve:-
when user scroll up then I want to collapse the Top Bar and when user scroll down then if user achieve the top while scrolling down then I want to appear the Top Bar not every time when user scroll Down?, Please Help me

and How you add the video?

I edited my answer. If it resolves your issue, please mark this answer as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of the answer. And to upload a video here, you need to convert it to gif file format, there are online tools available to do this.

Alternatively, you can just put your TopAppBar as the first item in your LazyColumn.

with if  Statement the top bar didn't appear when i am in the top and scrolling down and with onPostScroll the Top Bar didn't animating when i scroll first time when i scroll all the way down then it animating it? and  I don't have Lazy Column, ``` I update my Answer I add A video that with if statement````

Oh Bro, Why Don't Say u have to use both overrided functions, I was using one of them. Now its Working Fine, Thank You so Much

I found the Problem I just Add Height Modifier in My App Bar.
so whenever I scroll so it also moves the space that remains in the App Bar

I have to gave the exact height to the Composable that I don't want. how Can I gave the Wrap Height or without Height


and How You add Video, How can I Add Video?


  // Top Bar Scroll Connection
    val topBarMaxHeight: Int = with(density) { (30).dp.roundToPx() }
    val topBarScrollConnection: CollapsingAppBarNestedScrollConnection =
        remember(topBarMaxHeight) {
            CollapsingAppBarNestedScrollConnection(topBarMaxHeight)
        }


                        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                            title = {
                                Text(
                                    text = if(tabPagerState.currentPage == 0) "News" else "Events",
                                )
                            },
                            navigationIcon = {
                                IconButton(onClick = {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        drawerState.open()
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    Icon(
                                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu,
                                        contentDescription = "Icon for Navigation Drawer",
                                    )
                                }
                            },
                            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                                containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                                scrolledContainerColor = Color.Transparent
                            ),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .statusBarsPadding()
                                .then(
                                    with(density) {
                                        Modifier
                                            .height( // I Add this Height
                                                (topBarMaxHeight + topBarScrollConnection.appBarOffset).toDp()
                                            )
                                    }
                                )
                                .offset { IntOffset(0, topBarScrollConnection.appBarOffset) }
                        )


I Add Height so when ever I scroll so the it moves the height of TopAppBar Also that before it remains.
